# Ayuda con Web Service en Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, webservice

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta a un `web service` **`Resful`** por **`GET`**, este es mi función:

```
function enviar_as (orden)
{

    var codigo_unidad = '0902'; 
    if (confirm("Deseas enviar datos")){    
    $.ajax({    
           url: "http://host.com/wsdesarollo/datalab/",
           type: "GET",
           dataType:'json',  
           data: {'dlnuor':orden,'dlunme':codigo_unidad},       
           success: function(datos){
                load(1);
           }
    });
    }
}
```

Este mensaje me presenta:

```
URL solicitada:http://host.com/wsdesarollo/datalab/?dlnuor=142024&dlunme=0902
Método de la petición:GET
Dirección remota:186.x.x.x:80
Código de estado: 301 Moved Permanently
```

Alguien me puede guiar que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Ese mensaje donde se te presenta? es lo que vienen en network o en load? o en dónde?

Comment: en network amigo

Comment: `host.com/wsdesarollo/datalab/?dlnuor=142024&dlunme=0902` es tu página o es una api externa?

Answer (score 0):

la función ajax de jquery esta bien, tienes que tenes en cuenta que `dataType:'json'` indica que recibirás un `json`, ahora la dirección a la que apuntas `"http://host.com/wsdesarollo/datalab/"` veo que no tienes ningún archivo ejemplo `http://host.com/wsdesarollo/datalab/data.php`, cuando devuelve el servicio pones una función `load(1)`, pon mejor `console.log(datos)` a ver que te regresa yo le adicionaría otras cositas al `ajax` para poder ver el error ahí te lo escribo:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://host.com/wsdesarollo/datalab/data.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {'dlnuor':orden,'dlunme':codigo_unidad},
        cache: false,
        success: function(datos) {
          console.log(datos);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```